# B(H) as a direct sum of a closed two sided ideal and a subalgebra

Tags: banach-spaces, oa.operator-algebras

Let $B(H)$ is the C*-algebra of all bounded linear operators on 
Hilbert space $H$. Are there a closed two-sided ideal $I$ and a 
subalgebra $A$ of $B(H)$ such that $B(H)=I \oplus A$ (direct sum I and A)?

Comment: The tag is inappropriate; I changed it.

Answer (score 12):

$K(H)$, the compact operators on $H$, is the only proper closed ideal in $B(H)$ when $H$ is a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space, and $K(H)$ is not complemented in $B(H)$ (because if it were the diagonal compact operators would be complemented in the diagonal bounded operators, which is to say that $c_0$ would be complemented in $\ell_\infty$).

Comment: Do you know anything about general case of H?
Would you please let me know.

Comment: For general $H$ the ideals are $K(H)$ and, for each cardinal '$\aleph' \le$'  the dimension $\aleph$ of $H$, the set of operators whose ranges have dimension less than $\aleph$.  If such an ideal were complemented in $B(H)$ you argue that you would have the functions in '$\ell_\infty(\aleph')$' whose support has cardinality  less than $\aleph$ is complemented in  '$\ell_\infty(\aleph')$', which it is not. 
But I don't recall an easy argument that it is not complemented.  In the separable case, it is basically  Phillips' lemma that $c_0$ is not complemented in $\ell_\infty$ and the result is in

Comment: ...text books (e.g., Albiac-Kalton).  


Answer (score 11):

Let me complement Bill's answer. It is basically the same idea.

Gramsch and Luft described the lattice of closed ideals of $B(H)$ where is $H$ a non-separable Hilbert space.

> B. Gramsch, [Eine Idealstruktur Banachscher Operatoralgebren](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN00218219X&IDDOC=252638), *J. Reine Angew. Math.* **225** (1967),
>   97–115.
>
> E. Luft, [The two-sided closed ideals of the algebra of bounded linear operators of a Hilbert space](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/100858/CzechMathJ_18-1968-4_4.pdf), *Czechoslovak Math J.* **18** (1968), 595–605.

They proved that for a non-separable Hilbert space $H$ with density character ${\rm dens}\; H$ (this is the minimal cardinality of a dense subset) all the closed ideals of $B(H)$ are of the form $\{0\}$, $K(H)$ (the compact operators) and

$$K_\lambda(H) = \{T\in B(H)\colon \mbox{dens }T[H]< \lambda\}$$

where $\lambda\leqslant\kappa^+$. Certainly, $$B(H) = K_{({\rm dens}\; H)^+}(H).$$ 
Hence, we are interested in the case only where $\lambda\leqslant  {\rm dens}\; H$.

Fix an orthonormal basis for $H$ and identify operators on $H$ with matrices with respect to this basis. Consider the Banach space $\ell_\infty^\lambda({\rm dens}\; H)$ of all bounded complex-valued functions on the cardinal ${\rm dens}\; H$ with at most $<\lambda$ non-zero entries, endowed with the sup-norm.

If you intersect the ideal $K_\lambda(H)$ with the diagonal masa (that is, $\ell_\infty({\rm dens}\; H)$) then you'll get precisely $\ell_\infty^\lambda({\rm dens}\; H)$. The diagonal masa is complemented because $\ell_\infty({\rm dens}\; H)$ is an injective Banach space. Consequently, if $K_\lambda(H)$ was complemented in $B(H)$ then $\ell_\infty^\lambda({\rm dens}\; H)$ would be complemented in $\ell_\infty({\rm dens}\; H)$. This is however a contradiction because $\ell_\infty^\lambda({\rm dens}\; H)$ is not injective (see [this paper](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebs.um.es%2Favileslo%2Fmiwiki%2Flib%2Fexe%2Ffetch.php%3Fid%3Dinvestigacion%26cache%3Dcache%26media%3Dsepinject.pdf&ei=2Xs-UazFJfON7AaejYGYCA&usg=AFQjCNERZJYtB7taofZDFiEMhRDu4xfNAg) for a discussion of this space and its injectivity-like properties).

*Proof of non-injectivity of* $\ell_\infty^\lambda(\kappa)$: Assume $\ell_\infty^\lambda(\kappa)$ is injective. Manifestly, it contains $c_0(\kappa)$. Then by Rosenthal's theorem

> H.P. Rosenthal, [On relatively disjoint families of measures, with some applications
>   to Banach space theory](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm37/sm3712.pdf), *Studia Math.*, **37** (1970), 13–36.

it would contain a copy of $\ell_\infty(\kappa)$ and by Pełczyński's decomposition method, it would be isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(\kappa)$; a contradiction.

EDIT 05.05.15: This is actually an ancient observation by Pełczyński and Sudakov:

> A. Pełczyński and V. N. Sudakov, [Remark on non-complemented subspaces of the space $m(S)$](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm9/cm9111.pdf), *Colloq. Math.* **19** (1962), 85-88.

EDIT: As Bill pointed out we have to be careful why this is indeed impossible. Under GCH this is evident but life would be too easy with GCH. Actually, to see this is a result in ZFC, one has to tweak the argument in Paragraph d) on page 12 of the hyperlinked paper by replacing $\mathbb{N}$ with $\lambda$ and $\aleph_1$ with $\lambda$. Then the whole proof carries over. (Frankly, I learnt it from one of the authors of this paper some time ago and presumed that it is well-known. My apologies for that.)

Comment: @Tomek:  The argument you suggest at the end only shows that $\ell_\infty^\lambda({\rm dens}\; H)$ is not $1$-injective.

Comment: Thank you, Bill. I hope my answer is now fairly complete.

Comment: @Tomek: Yes, I saw that argument, too, but why is $\ell_\infty^\lambda(\kappa)$ not isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(\kappa)$? The latter space has density character $2^\kappa$ and the former density character sup $\{ 2^\alpha: \alpha < \lambda\}$, so non isomorphism is easy under the generalized continuum hypothesis.  Absent GCH, I did not at first see a simple reason. Now I do, but I'll  wait a bit before posting in case you want to think about it some more.

Comment: @Bill, I agree that it requires some justification. To do this, one can tweak the argument for the fact that there is no 1-1 operator form $\ell_\infty(\omega_1)$ to $\ell_\infty^{\omega_1}(\kappa)$. I am sorry for just pointing a reference but today I have no time for going into more details. Of course, I am very curious about your proof!

Comment: @Tomek:  What I had in mind was $\ell_1(2^\kappa)$ embeds into $\ell_\infty(\kappa)$ but not into $\ell_\infty^\lambda(\kappa)$.  The former is an immediate consequence of the fact that $C(\{-1,1\})^\kappa$ is a quotient of $\ell_1(\kappa)$; the latter is an easy exercise.

Comment: Nice answer, Tomek. For the sake of completeness$^\ast$, I mention that, with the definitions given in your answer, $K_\lambda(H)$ is not closed in $B(H)$ when $\lambda< dens(H)$ is of cofinality $\omega$; similarly, $\ell_\infty^\lambda (dens(H))$ is not closed in $\ell_\infty(dens(H))$ when $\lambda< dens(H)$ is of cofinality $\omega$ (these spaces are otherwise closed in their respective overspaces). The definition of $\ell_\infty^\lambda (dens(H))$ should presumably be those $f\in \ell_\infty(dens(H))$ with $\vert\{ \alpha\in dens(H)\mid\vert f(\alpha)\vert>\epsilon\}\vert <\lambda$.

Comment: For $K_\lambda(H)$, you can of course just take the uniform closure in the case I mention above to get the desired closed ideal; I guess this special case is why Luft (and, later, Daws) used a generalised notion of total boundedness rather than density character to define the operator ideals $K_\lambda$.

Comment: $ ^\ast$ - I'll show myself out...

Comment: Right, Phillip.

For my "simple" argument that $\ell_1(\kappa)$ does not embed into (the closure of) 
$\ell_\infty^\lambda(\kappa)$ I implicitly used $\lambda < \gamma$ implies $2^\lambda < 2^\gamma$.  

Comment: In fact, it looks not quite trivial that $\lambda < \gamma$ implies 
$\ell_\infty(\lambda)$ is not isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(\gamma)$. The simplest argument I see is that $\ell_2(\gamma)$ embeds into $\ell_\infty(\gamma)$ but not into $\ell_\infty(\lambda)$ (weakly compact subsets of $\ell_\infty(\lambda)$ have density character at most $\lambda$ because there is a separating family of continuous linear functionals of cardinality $\lambda$).

Comment: @Bill, under Martin's axiom and failure of CH, we have $2^{\omega} = 2^{\omega_1}$, I am afraid.

Comment: For my "simple" argument that $\ell_1(2^\kappa)$ does not embed into 
(the closure of) $\ell_\infty^\lambda(\kappa)$ I implicitly used $\lambda < \gamma$ implies $2^\lambda < 2^\gamma$. (Correcting typo in earlier comment.)